# Splitting parts of a DHCP log and storing into a variable using python

Tags: python, split, dhcp

How do you split part of a simple line from DHCP Log files using python
E.g

```
Dec 15 09:57:17 6con-dhcp-01 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 103.26.222.234 from 14:91:82:ab:4d:32 via eth1
```

I want to split the above line into different parts and store it in a variable

```
Date = Dec 15 
Time = 09:57:17
IP Address = 103.26.222.234
Mac Address = 14:91:82:ab:4d:32
```

I already tried using .split() but to no avail.

```
var = Dec 15 09:57:17 6con-dhcp-01 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 103.26.222.234 from 14:91:82:ab:4d:32 via eth1

datas = var.split()


for data in datas:
print(data)
```

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48181992/edit) button to update your question.

Comment: i tried using .split() to experiment around so that i can display the different parts of it in different lines instead of it being chunked together. However the method which i tried doesnt really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an way to split them and store them in variables

```
import re
splitted = re.split(' ', var)
print splitted
```

The output will be in this format:

```
['Dec', '15', '09:57:27', '6con-dhcp-01', 'dhcpd:', 'DHCPREQUEST', 'for', '132.147.83.212', 'from', '44:d9:e7:41:ee:77', 'via', 'eth1\n']
```

With the code below i can store the separated part into variables

```
Monthdatetime = splitted[0] + ' ' + splitted[1] + ' ' + splitted[2]
print Monthdatetime
```

The output would be:

```
Dec 15 09:57:27
```

Answer (score 0):

For exacting data of any log file, you should consider the text pattern first. And then segment the required data. Last, use a regex tool to extract the information.

Comment: I have already extracted out all the lines that contain only "DHCPREQUEST" because only those lines are the ones i need from the whole log file. However i am not very sure in this case what are some of the regex i can use as each line come with different IP Addresses and Mac Addresses.

Comment: You can segment the Regex too.